# xaml onPlatform DateTime binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Having a DatePicker, I'm trying to set the MaximumDate property by binding a DateTime just for Android devices.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="FromDatePicker" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
       Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='5, 0, 0, 0'}"
       HorizontalOptions="Start" Date="{Binding FromDate}"
       MaximumDate="{OnPlatform Android={Binding FromMaximumDate}}">
</DatePicker>
```

I have also tried the following way:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="FromDatePicker" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='5, 0, 0, 0'}"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" Date="{Binding FromDate}">

    <DatePicker.MaximumDate>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="sys:DateTime">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="{Binding FromMaximumDate}"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </DatePicker.MaximumDate>
</DatePicker>
```

But it doesn't work. I just get **Specified cast not valid**. What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide more code about the Page.cs and FromMaximumDate, which can help me to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into the same issue. You can use TypeArguments="BindingBase". Most likely vs is going to show xaml intellisense error **Property does not support values of type 'Onplatform'1 (BindingBase)** but is going to work anyway.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="FromDatePicker" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='5, 0, 0, 0'}"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" Date="{Binding FromDate}">

    <DatePicker.MaximumDate>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase" Android="{Binding ToMinimumDate}"/>
    </DatePicker.MaximumDate>
</DatePicker>
```